# Can I determine the response class from a superagent response?

Tags: javascript, http, http-error, superagent

I'd like to check for [client errors (4xx) and server errors (5xx)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-48) in a superagent `err.status`. From the HTTP RFC:

> The first digit of the status-code defines the **class** of response.

I can easily write:

```
var _isClientOrServerError = function(errStatus){
    var errorRange = Math.floor(err.status / 100)
    return ( [5, 4].includes(errorRange) ) 
}
```

But is there a better way to determine the response class from the request?

Eg.:

```
if ( res.class === 'SERVER_ERROR' )
```

Or similar?

Happy too if there's a plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Superagent calls the HTTP response class the **type** and the **`statusType`** field contain the response class. From the docs:

```
// status / class
res.status = status;
res.statusType = type;

// basics
res.info = 1 == type;
res.ok = 2 == type;
res.clientError = 4 == type;
res.serverError = 5 == type;
res.error = 4 == type || 5 == type;
```

So `res.statusType` is the field that contains the response class (it's a JS `Number` between 1 and 5), but checking `res.error` is enough to detect 4xx or 5xx errors.